# How to allow users to add their own Category into the string Array?

Tags: android, arrays

Currently, I'm doing an android app, where I stored some categories inside a string array and get them into the spinner.

Now the problem is, if the user needs to add their own category, is it possible to add their categories inside the string array? Or do I need to store these categories inside the database?

This is my string array:

```
<string-array name="array_categories">
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Clothing</item>
    <item>Transportation</item>
    <item>Entertainment</item>
    <item>Halls</item>
    <item>Jewellery</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>`
```

Comment: Obviously you need to use database to keep the added values

Comment: if just only for this simple purpose, i usually just write/read a serializable object into the sdcard. database is for complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

Resources stored in application are generated during compile-time and are read-only during runtime. You can't modify them.

You could try to use SQlite database for storing information. The first time you run application it will take data from XML Array and store in database. Next time when you update from the server you can just add/modify your database.